# How to put Chart in ASP.net website as it is in MS Excel?

Tags: asp.net, excel

I have this chart in MS Excel , I need to use same in ASP.net website I created. I have all the point data but how do I get same chart ?

[image]

Comment: You'll need a library that can draw that type of chart.

Comment: If you know any good library then pls suggest.

Comment: It doesn't look viable to me. If I were you I'd rather code this chart with client-side JavaScript + HTML5 canvas than search for some heavy library that will nevertheless fail to draw it as it appears in Excel.

Comment: Well, I used MS Chart control and that solved my problem. I had to move my website from framework 5 to 4.5 as there is no radar chart control in 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using below code in .net version 4.5.

HTML:

```
<div id="divRadarChart" runat="server"> 
            <table class="sampleTable">
                <tr>
                    <td width="812" class="tdchart">
                        <asp:CHART id="Chart2" runat="server" Width="812px" Height="696px"  Palette="None" BackColor="#F3DFC1" BorderColor="181, 64, 1" BorderlineDashStyle="Solid" BackGradientStyle="DiagonalLeft" BorderWidth="2">
                            <titles>
                                <asp:Title ShadowColor="32, 0, 0, 0" Font="Trebuchet MS, 14.25pt, style=Bold" ShadowOffset="3" Text="Overall Rating" ForeColor="26, 59, 105"></asp:Title>
                            </titles>
                        <%--    <legends>
                                <asp:Legend IsTextAutoFit="False" Name="Default" BackColor="Transparent" Font="Trebuchet MS, 8.25pt, style=Bold" Alignment="Far">
                                    <position y="74.08253" height="14.23021" width="19.34047" x="74.73474"></position>
                                </asp:Legend>
                            </legends>--%>
                            <borderskin skinstyle="Emboss"></borderskin>
                            <series>
                                <asp:Series MarkerBorderColor="64, 64, 64" MarkerSize="9" Name="Series1" ChartType="Radar" BorderColor="180, 26, 59, 105" Color="220, 65, 140, 240" ShadowOffset="0"></asp:Series>
                            </series>
                            <chartareas>
                                <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1" BorderColor="64, 64, 64, 64" BackSecondaryColor="White" BackColor="OldLace" ShadowColor="Transparent">

                                    <position y="5" height="98" width="100" x="5"></position>
                                    <axisy linecolor="64, 64, 64, 64">
                                        <labelstyle font="Trebuchet MS, 8.25pt, style=Bold" />
                                        <majorgrid linecolor="64, 64, 64, 64" />
                                        <majortickmark size="0.6" />  
                                    </axisy>
                                    <axisx linecolor="64, 64, 64, 64">
                                        <labelstyle font="Trebuchet MS, 8.25pt, style=Bold" />
                                        <majorgrid linecolor="64, 64, 64, 64" />
                                    </axisx>
                                </asp:ChartArea>
                            </chartareas>
                        </asp:CHART>
                    </td> 
                </tr> 
            </table> 

        </div>
```

codebehind:

```
using System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting;
using System.Drawing;

 protected void RadarChart(double leadermark, double opmark, double procmark, double custmark )
    {
        // Populate series data
        double[] yValues = { leadermark, opmark, procmark, custmark }; 
        string[] xValues = { "Quality1", "Quality2", "Quality3", "Quality4"};
        Chart2.Series["Series1"].Points.DataBindXY(xValues, yValues); 

        // Set radar chart style
        Chart2.Series["Series1"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Radar;
        Chart2.Series["Series1"]["RadarDrawingStyle"] = "Area";  
        Chart2.Series["Series1"].BorderColor = Color.FromArgb(100, 100, 100);
        Chart2.Series["Series1"].BorderWidth = 1; 
        // Set circular area drawing style
        Chart2.Series["Series1"]["AreaDrawingStyle"] = "Polygon";
        Chart2.Series["Series1"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
        Chart2.Series["Series1"].LabelBorderWidth = 2;  

        // Set labels style
        Chart2.Series["Series1"]["CircularLabelsStyle"] = "Horizontal"; 

        Chart2.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Minimum = 0;
        Chart2.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Maximum = 100;
        Chart2.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Interval = 10; 
        Chart2.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "{#}%";


    }
```